# Jquery cross domain request not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a cross domain request using Jquery ajax.

My code here:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://my.domain.com/api/user/66f041e16a60928b05a7e228a89c3799/events/c60d870eaad6a3946ab3e8734466e532',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain : true,
    success: function(eventDetailsResponse) {
                response = JSON.stringify(eventDetailsResponse);
                console.log(eventDetailsResponse);
             },
    error: function() {  },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                   xhr.setRequestHeader('key1', 'value1');
                   xhr.setRequestHeader('key2', 'value2');
                   xhr.setRequestHeader('key3', 'value3');
                }
});
```

Comment: I tried already when it was asking user name and password (Authentication required).

Comment: take a look at response if you have CORS enabled and check if you are really sending `json` or `jsonp`.

Comment: I'm not sending any data, i'm getting json from server.